# ¿se puede añadir excepciones en css?

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
p {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  }
 li { /*font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;*/
  font-style: oblique; }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven mi menu que tiene la etiqueta

asi también en la segunda imagen se puede observar al final una lista puntuada que está en oblicuas, ya que este también tiene la etiqueta

. A mi menu le quiero agregar una clase a las etiquetas

```html
<nav>
  <ul><li>
<div class="contenedor">
     <a href="#" class="open">INICIO</a>
  </div>
</li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal1" class="open"> ACERCA DE </a>
      <section id="openmodal1" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> acerca de</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Este sitio abarca tutoriales para dar soluciones destinadas a resolver dudas acerca de todo tipo de ideas útiles para el internauta</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal2" class="open">POLITICA DE PRIVACIDAD</a>
      <section id="openmodal2" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> politica de privacidad</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Esta permitido compartir todo el contenido de este sitio, más no está permitido copiar cual fiel copia, para usarlo en el desarrollo de otro sitio web, todo o parte del contenido de mi sitio web. En cualquier caso que se inserte cualquier parte del contenido en otro sitio web se deberá hacer referencia de que se está compartiendo el contenido y de forma notoria que dicho contenido es de mi autoria: Susana Alexadra Loor García y de que se extrajo de: <a href="https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com">https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/</a> Por lo tanto se establece que se respetará este sitio web como propiedad de la autora, y nadie se podrá adujudicar a su autoria todo del contenido de dicho sitio</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal3" class="open"> CONTACTO</a>
      <section id="openmodal3" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> CONTACTO</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Comunicate con nosotros a este correo susanaloorgarcia@gmail.com</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div> </li>
    <li>
       <div class="contenedor">
        <a target="_blank" class="open" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsYcSASeuWbHFBZJXy6SJEA?sub_confirmation=1">YOUTUBE</a>
       </div>
 </li>
  </ul>
      </nav>
```

para diferenciarlas de estas

```html
<ul>
<li>simplemente arrastran hacia afuera</li></ul><br><p align="justify"> Para
volver a convertir esta pestaña en una
ventana</p><br> <ul>
<li>pues tienen que recordar que
tienen que tener abierta la otra ventana
aquí sí va a poder arrastrar hacia
arriba y soltar</li>
<li>otra forma de hacerlo
una vez que ustedes tengan creada su
ventana
es haciendo clic en este botón de en medio de maximizar</li>
<li>la ventana puede estar superpuestas no
es necesario bajar la puede estar un
poco más grande y simplemente arrastran
esta ventana hacia las otras pestañas</li></ul>
```

entonces yo quiero que si a mi menu le pongo class=excepcion. No se como poner en css para que todas las etiquetas

tengan oblicuas, excepto la clase excelpcion

Comment: Usas Windows 10, te recomiendo que utilices Snipping Tool (incluida por defecto en Windows) en lugar de hacer capturas de pantalla. De ese modo podrás elegir las partes que quieres que se guarden en lugar de todo el monitor y será más fácil identificar el problema dentro de la imagen.

Comment: Y lee [ask] y [¿Cómo darle formato a mis publicaciones utilizando Markdown o HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). La pregunta es difícil de leer porque no se le está dando el formato adecuado al código inline.

Comment: Voto como no está claro lo que se pregunta ya que la pregunta en sí esta muy mal redactada y no acabo de entenderla exactamente. Por favor, edita tu pregunta para que quede mucho más claro lo que quieres exactamente.

Comment: Te recomiendo que reescribas la pregunta: explica qué tienes ahora y qué quieres conseguir. Lo que necesitas no es una "excepción", sino una clase con estilos que tenga más prioridad.

Comment: La solución es sencilla: `.excepcion { font-style: normal; }`. Con eso todos los elementos con clase `excepcion` tendrán formato normal (sin cursiva). Revisa la [documentación de `font-style` aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/font-style).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Si existen las excepciones en css**, es un selector conocido como `:not(.clase)`, pero no te lo recomiendo para tu caso. Igual te muestro como funciona.

Digamos tienes 2 listas donde en una `li` son obliquas por defecto y en la otra no:

```
<ul>
  <li> Algo </li>
  <li> Algo </li>
</ul>

<ul class="no-oblicuas">
  <li> Algo </li>
  <li> Algo </li>
</ul>
```

En el css, sería algo así

```
ul:not(no-oblicuas) li{
  font-style: italic;
}
```

De esa manera le indicamos que todos los `li` por defecto serán italicas, excepto la que tenga la clase **`no-oblicuas`**.

Pero **realmente te recomiendo** es el uso de las **multiclases**, una para cuando necesites itálicas en las listas y otra cuando no, algo así:

```
<ul class="lista italica">
  <li> Algo </li>
  <li> Algo </li>
</ul>

<ul class="lista negrita">
  <li> Algo </li>
  <li> Algo </li>
</ul>
```

Y en el css:

```
.lista{
  font-style: normal;
}

.lista.itálica li{
  font-style: italic;
}

.lista.negrita li{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Esto aplica para usarse con cualquier etiquetas, no necesariamente listas, pueden ser `p`, `div`, `span`, etc.

Pero es una recomendación, tomando en cuenta las buenas prácticas de maquetar en internet, no es una norma, ya depende de ti.

Answer (score 0):

Podría generar dos clases para eso, una para las oblicua y otras para que no las haga así:

```
   .oblicua p {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
      }
    .oblicua li { /*font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;*/
        font-style: oblique; }
   .excepcion p {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
      }
    .excepcion  li { /*font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;*/ }
```